# DynamoDB UpdateItem with ReturnValues parameter returns nothing on failed ConditionExpression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Using aws/aws-sdk-php 3.21.6. I must be misunderstanding how ReturnValues works when a ConditionExpression meets the ConditionalCheckFailedException error.

What I'm hoping is that if the ConditionExpression fails, which in turn triggers the ConditionalCheckFailedException, that I can catch this exception and then get access via ReturnValues to the new Attributes from DD.

The docs [Attributes I'm expecting from ReturnValues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPItemOperationsExample.html) seem to imply this.

From testing, however, ReturnValues only returns Attributes if the ConditionExpression is true, not when it fails.

```
$response = $client->updateItem([
    'TableName' => 'MyTable',
    'Key' => [
        'customer_url' => [
            'S' => 'someurl.com'
        ],
        'customer_platform' => [
            'S' => 'some_platform'
        ]
    ],
    'ExpressionAttributeNames' => [
        '#C' => 'createdAt'
    ],
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  [
        ':val1' => [
            'S' => '2017-01-24T14:15:32'
        ],
        ':val2' => [
            'S' => '2017-01-24T14:15:30'
        ]
    ],
    'UpdateExpression' => 'set #C = :val1',
    'ConditionExpression' => '#C = :val2', // :val2 originally was 2017-01-24T14:15:30, before attempting to update to 2017-01-24T14:15:32. If I change the field to 2017-01-24T14:15:31, before running this update it will throw the ConditionalCheckFailedException
    'ReturnValues' => 'ALL_NEW'
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `ReturnValues` is populated *only* if an `updateItem` succeeds. If it fails, because of `ConditionalCheckFailedException` or any other reason, `ReturnValues` will be null.

Supporting documentation from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_updateItem), with *emphasis* mine:

> Use ReturnValues if you want to get the item attributes as they appeared either before or after *they were updated*.

Comment: what if we want to get the record if the update fails?

Comment: It seems to me that getting the old values on a failed update would be a key feature, especially for implementing idempotency at the API level.